# Java MediaPlaye Problem: Song does not play when a button is selected

Tags: java, javafx

I am designing a program that essentially functions as a music player. It works perfectly fine within Eclipse, but when I export it, none of the buttons I created play music as intended.

To investigate this, I designed a new button that would call a test method that gets a random song from a specified directory, plays this song, and returns a String "cat". Next, I inserted an if statement below the line where I called the method to see if a value of "cat" had been assigned. If this was successful, the button would change color to red. This would allow me to see whether the test method was completed, independently of whether music had played. NOTE: multiPlayer is an instance of a MediaPlayer class that I designed.

**ActionEventListener for test button**:

```
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
        String x = multiPlayer.testThis();
        if(x.equals("cat")) {
            button.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        }
        });
```

**Method called by button selection**:

```
public String testThis()
{
    JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    File file = getRandomSong();
    Media hit = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
    mediaPlayer.play();
    return "cat";
}
```

I then went line-by-line of the test method, commenting lines out to see where the method fails upon export. I discovered that the line where I instantiate a new JFXPanel is the source of the problem. For example, if I run the getRandomSong method, the button changes color just fine; however, if I include the new JFXPanel() line, the button fails to change color, suggesting that the method has not worked.

Can anyone provide advice to me about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try printing the values of `file.getAbsolutePath()` and `file.exists()`.

Comment: In addition to printing out the values suggested by VGR, you should: (1) Make sure you aren't silently swallowing exceptions anywhere; (2) add a listener to the `Media#error` property and call `printStackTrace()` if it becomes non-null; (3) launch the exported application from the command line and see if any errors (i.e. stack traces) are printed to the console.

Comment: You should also [edit] your question to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem. For instance, how does `getRandomSong()` work?